# Error en Procedimiento Almacenado MySql

Tags: mysql

Soy nuevo intentando trabajar con procedimientos almacenados en `MySql` este `SP` que intento crear a continuación es para verificar el acceso de un usuario al sistema...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS verificarUsuarios; 
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE verificarUsuarios(IN _email VARCHAR(55), IN _pass VARCHAR(55), OUT _validacion BIT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @_resultado INT DEFAULT 0;
        SET _validacion = 0;        
        SELECT @_resultado := COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE email = _email AND password = _pass;
        IF @_resultado > 0 THEN
            SET _validacion = 1;
        ELSE
            SET _validacion = 0;
        END IF
    END
//
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintaxis cerca de '@resultado;
    SET _validacion = 0;
    SELECT @_resultado := COUNT(*) FROM us' en la linea 3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor incluye los detalles del error en texto. Puedes dejar la imagen también si quieres. Pero es útil tenerlo en texto también.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias en un momento añado el texto... y muchas gracias por responderme la duda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los nombres de variables locales a un procedimiento no pueden comenzar con `@`. De modo que la variable para el resultado debería ser declarada de esta forma (el `DEFAULT` en realidad no es necesario tampoco):

```
DECLARE _resultado INT;
```

Luego, para poder asignar el resultado de la consulta a esa variable local, debes usar la claúsula `INTO`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) into _resultado FROM usuarios ...
```

Y finalmente, detalles adicionales:

- Te falta un punto y coma después del `END IF`
- El `SET _validacion = 0;` es redudante. Lo puedes quitar.

El procedimiento quedaría de la forma siguiente:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS verificarUsuarios; 
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE verificarUsuarios(IN _email VARCHAR(55), IN _pass VARCHAR(55), OUT _validacion BIT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _resultado INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) into _resultado FROM usuarios WHERE email = _email AND password = _pass;
        IF _resultado > 0 THEN
            SET _validacion = 1;
        ELSE
            SET _validacion = 0;
        END IF;
    END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Edición**

Tal vez valga la pena convertir el procedimiento a una función para poder ejecutarlo con una sintaxis más conveniente:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE FUNCTION verificarUsuarios(_email VARCHAR(55), _pass VARCHAR(55)) RETURNS BIT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _resultado INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) into _resultado FROM usuarios WHERE email = _email AND password = _pass;
        IF _resultado > 0 THEN
            RETURN 1;
        ELSE
            RETURN 0;
        END IF;
    END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Entonces puedes llamarlos de esta forma:

```
SET @resultadoValidacion = verificarUsuarios("user@gmail.com","passuser");
```

Comment: Disculpa, una duda más, si lo quiero mando llamar de la siguiente manera `CALL verificarUsuarios("user@gmail.com","passuser")` me pide el tercer parametro de validación, ¿como puedo evitar que me lo pida?, y ¿que solo me lo arroje, con el email y pass como en el `CALL` que mencione aquí mismo?

Comment: Con un procedure, no creo que sea posible. Tendrías que convertir el procedure a una función. En ese caso, la llamada ya no sería con `CALL`, sino que se parecería mas bien a `set @var = verificarUsuarios("user@gmail.com","passuser");`.

Comment: En efecto, es lo que estaba checando, mas sin embargo, lo deje como un `SP` , pero al momento de llamarlo desde la ventana SQL de phpmyadmin con `CALL verificarUsuarios('antonio291093@gmail.com','linkinpark',@salida);` **Este si es un usuario de mi BD, no me arroja nada, ¿sabes a que se deberá?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir por, **no te arroja nada**? Algo te debe devolver, ¿no?  Y te menciono que en mi respuesta original se me había quedado `IF @_resultado > 0 THEN` por error.  Ahora lo he corregido, pero verifica que no se te quedó el `@` allí también.

Comment: Si, si observé ese detalle y le quite el `@` , a lo que me refiero es que yo tenía la idea de que al momento de llamar el `SP` de esta manera `CALL verificarUsuarios('antonio291093@gmail.com','linkinpark',@salida);` iba a obtener un pequeño resultado con @salida = 1, ya que este si es un usuario y password correctos de un registro, mas sin embargo, no me muestra siquiera, @salida = 0; , no me despliega nada al ejecutarlo